# Help with Windows RawInput

Tags: c++, input, windows

I am having some trouble to receive and interpret mouse movement data from RawInput. Generally mouse input seems to work, I can query mouse buttons and receive updates of mouse movement.

The problem is that data.mouse.lLastX and data.mouse.lLastX are both 0 if the data is relative. However when the data is absolute there is no problem. Does anybody know how this can happen?

Let me know if you need some code in order to help.

Comment: When are the values `0`? If it's set to relative, those numbers will be `0` if the mouse did not move the since the last time an update occurred.

Comment: This happens as soon as I move the mouse. Then a WM_INPUT message is coming in and the values are 0. RawInput definitely recognizes a mouse move but doesn't give me the x ynd y values at all